# Design help: Modelling a shell experience in Haskell

Tags: shell, haskell

I am trying to make a virtual shell experience using Haskell. What I mean by this is that I mean to create a program, that when executed from a terminal window, drops you into an environment that allows you to execute a subset of familiar commands (for instance, `cd` and `mkdir`) among others.

The filesystem will be entirely virtual, as in it does not touch anything on disk.

My initial sketch (below) feels clunky, so much in fact that composing an MWE was a drag, I am very unaccustomed to representing datastructures functionally and would like to get some pointers on how to turn this experience around. Any reference programs with available source code would be helpful as would any tips or lines of thinking.

I have written the following

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Either as Either

type Name = String
type Content = String
type Error = String

data DiskEntry = File Name Content
               | Directory {name :: Name
                 , entries :: Map.Map String DiskEntry
                 } deriving (Show)


-- | The 'mkdir' function creates a new directory inside the given
-- directory.  Attempts to create a 'DiskEntry' with the name 'name'
-- inside the given 'directory'. If an entry with that name already
-- exists an error is returned. If such an entry does not exist
-- then it is added to the destination 'DiskEntry' and is returned
-- as part of a tuple, where the left entry is the old (modified) 'DiskEntry'
-- and the right entry is the newly created 'DiskEntry'.
mkdir :: Name -> DiskEntry -> Either Error (DiskEntry, DiskEntry)
mkdir entryName destination = do
  if Map.member entryName $ entries destination then do
    Left $ "mkdir: cannot create directory '" ++ entryName ++ "': File exists"
    else do let
              newDirectory = Directory entryName Map.empty    
              d = addToEntries entryName newDirectory destination
              in Right (d, newDirectory)

addToEntries :: Name -> DiskEntry -> DiskEntry -> DiskEntry
addToEntries newEntryName newEntry destination = do
  let
    updatedEntries = Map.insert newEntryName newEntry (entries destination)
    d = Directory (name destination) updatedEntries
    in d

ls :: DiskEntry -> [DiskEntry]
ls currentDirectory = map snd $ Map.toList $ entries currentDirectory

root :: DiskEntry
root = Directory "/" Map.empty

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Pretend that we have several "Either Error (DiskEntry, DiskEntry)"
  -- We know that we have Right values, so get the first result from
  -- that and extract the first element in the tuple which is the
  -- newly modified "root" directory.
  let old = fst $ Either.rights [mkdir "bin" root] !! 0

  putStrLn "Connected. Take this shell, and may it serve you well."
  putStrLn "I will not you create anything yet, but there is a"
  putStrLn "directory, \"/\" which you are currently in."
  putStrLn "The `ls` command should let you see what else is there"
  putStrLn "I will do that for you now"

  putStrLn $ show $ ls old
```

which outputs to the following

```
➜  ls-adventures git:(master) ✗ ghci main.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :main
Connected. Take this shell, and may it serve you well.
I will not you create anything yet, but there is a
directory, "/" which you are currently in.
The `ls` command should let you see what else is there
I will do that for you now
[Directory {name = "bin", entries = fromList []}]
```

I am very malcontent with the means for updating directories, I would much more prefer that my function was capable of updating in place the referenced destination directory. Is this possible through something like the State Monad? Oh, and I assume the code looks horrendous, as in non-idiomatic Haskell?

Comment: You might like to look into Oleg's [zipperfs](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/zipper.html#zipper-fs).

Comment: You may want to use codereview.stackexchange.com for these sort of questions

Comment: It sounds like the author of this question is asking about ways to make the code do something different, which would be off-topic for Code Review. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/42632) for more details about what is on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: This is the sort of broad question that isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. Apart from the Code Review site, you might also get better results and more discussion if you post this to the [Haskell subreddit](http://haskell.reddit.com) or the @haskell-cafe mailing list.

Comment: I don't think this is a code review question, I think it is more along the lines of "how do I model this in Haskell?". One commonly used approach is define a [DSL](https://wiki.haskell.org/Embedded_domain_specific_language) often in the form of some Monad. Here you can use something like `StateT DirState (EitherT String IO)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, Filip, that is a braindead "on hold" reason (you didn't ask anyone to recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or off-site resource!), and actually your question on-topic, "how do I model a changing directory structure in Haskell"? The easiest way is, just use one big `Map Path FSEntry` with `data FSEntry = Dir | File ByteString` or so, and let the `Data.Map` crew optimize for you. If you don't like that, by all means use a zipper or some other trie with fingers into it. [(Overkill here.)](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/ConfluentTries_SWAT2008/paper.pdf)

Comment: I wonder if the [shell] tag is appropriate - after all, this is a question about Haskell.